# Showing multiple series with the same data in excel charts

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have three sets of data that I need to plot on the same chart. Coincidentally these three sets have the same data (all 0%). **Is there a way that I can show all three lines in the same plot area of a line chart in excel?**

Here is what I currently have:
[image]

I'm not sure exactly what my desired result would look like (if it's possible). Perhaps a dotted line with all three series colours?

Comment: What have you tried already? What does your data sheet look like? There really isn't enough information here to help.

Comment: I have to respectfully disagree. I've already described my data and asked a very specific question. I'm not looking for answers like "use a different chart type" or "split the series into different charts", because I know I can do these things already.

Comment: Unfortunately, you might have to mess around with the formatting of the series lines. I attempted to recreate using plot points, dashed lines, and different line thickness. The results were OK, but not what I'd call ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much googling and tinkering around I've given up trying to find a good solution. There are, however, some mediocre solutions to this issue without switching graph types.

As jrichall said in the comments you can play around with the formatting of the lines. First up are plot points. By themselves, I find they don't really help at all as seen in the below chart:
[image: Plot points]

One solution that showed more promise was changing the line type for each line. This result was hit and miss as the different dotted and dashed lines where not designed for this use case:
[image: Line Types]

The last solution that I tried that showed the most promise was changing the thicknesses of the lines such that the thinnest line was drawn last (shows up "on top of" the others) and the thickest line is drawn first. In this case Series 1 is drawn first (thickest) and Series 3 is drawn last (thinnest). While this is the best solution I tried, I found it was still better to use a different type of graph for my use case.
[image: Line Thicknesses]